# How to set decimal precision and suppress sci notation for printing scipy's f_oneway, specifically the pvalue (numpy.float64)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Apologies if my code isn't quite as eloquent as it could be, I'm just about getting started with using python for statistics, specifically in Jupyter Notebook.

For example, let's say I run a handful of simple analyses

```
Result1 = f_oneway (Pre1, Post1)
Result2 = f_oneway (Pre2, Post2)
Result3 = f_oneway (Pre3, Post3)
Result4 = f_oneway (Pre4, Post4)
Result5 = f_oneway (Pre5, Post5)
Result6 = f_oneway (Pre6, Post6)
```

This is how I would then print the results

```
print(Result1.pvalue)

print(Result2.pvalue)

print(Result3.pvalue)

print(Result4.pvalue)

print(Result5.pvalue)

print(Result6.pvalue)
```

The dilemma with this is how it would then present these values to me

```
0.010560577848593931

2.475000911458267e-06

0.05427475343595909

6.361645717956705e-06

0.03233992342571283

0.06797375874790515
```

I only require a p-value threshold of < 0.05. For the sake of how this data is being used, it is entirely unnecessary to show 18 decimal places. The use of scientific notation, I feel, serves to only make the result less easily readable to the people who will be seeing this. A precision of 5 decimal places is more than enough for my use.

I've tried np.set_printoptions(precision=5, suppress=True), however it seemed to not have any effect.

I've considered just hard coding the results, and presenting the results that use scientific notation just as "> 0.00000" However, while that fixes my presentation issue in this situation, I would much rather learn a real solution if one exists.

Comment: If you're just looking to present the p-values, look at `f-strings` something like `print(f'p-value is{result.pvalue:.4f}'). Note that this will be strings and not numbers so you can;t use it for comparison etc

Comment: `np.setprint..` only applies to numpy arrays.  Use regular python formatting (there are several styles)

Comment: Thank you both so much! Especially @SurajShourie! I do have some experience in programming but I'm still new to python, especially when it comes to presentation of information. No need to worry about comparisons in this case, but I'll absolutely keep that in mind going forward! Also @hpaulj, I believe the variable type for the items in the f_oneway function are both np.float64 in an array, and I assumed (I know I know, never assume with coding haha) that since they were using a numpy data type that the array would also be numpy but that doesn't appear to be the case, thank you though!